# Why CDbCacheDependency's query is executed twice?

Tags: php, caching, yii

I'm trying to cache some results retrieved from database using Yii framework 1.1.12. Here is what I am doing in short:

```
public static function getCategories()
{
    if (self::$_categories !== null)
        return self::$_categories;

    print "Getting categories...";    
    self::$_categories = Yii::app()->cache->get("categoriesList");
    if (self::$_categories === false)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM {{category}} WHERE id > 0 AND is_deleted = 0";
        $categoriesList = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();

        // Doing some work with $categoriesList and obtaining self::$_categories as the result
        // ...

        $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency("SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM {{category}}");
        Yii::app()->cache->set("categoriesList", self::$_categories, 3600, $dependency);
    }

    return self::$_categories;
}
```

Using the profiling tool I can see that everything works. At the first time both queries are executed (each query once):

```
SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM arrenda_category
SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM arrenda_category WHERE id > 0 AND is_deleted = 0
```

On further requests only first one is executed.

The problem is when I increase max value of `update_time` in `arrenda_category` table (even not using my own edit script - directly from MySQL command line) and refresh the page a count of `SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM arrenda_category` queries becomes equal to 2. Further refreshes give only one execution again. The interesting thing is if I clear the cache I have one execution of `SELECT MAX(...) ...` query too.

So I don't understand why a query of cache dependency class is executed twice on condition's change. Is there something wrong with my code or maybe anything else?

P.S. I'm sure that `SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM arrenda_category` can be executed only in function described above. I also see that the line `print "Getting categories..."` is reached once per page request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is expected.

**EXPLANATION**

Suppose the data is already in the cache. And when you call the function `getCategories()`  , the line `Yii::app()->cache->get("categoriesList")` will execute the dependancy query to check whether the data is changed. Since it is not changed the query is executed one time only.

Now you changed the `update_time` value externally ( or using some another code in your app ), and you call the `getCategories()` again,

1. The line `Yii::app()->cache->get("categoriesList")` executes the dependancy query to check whether the data in the cache is valid. It finds that data is invalid and returns false
2. Then the query `SELECT id, parent_id, name FROM {{category}} WHERE id > 0 AND is_deleted = 0` is executed to fetch the updated data from the database
3. The line `Yii::app()->cache->set("categoriesList", self::$_categories, 3600, $dependency);` **AGAIN** executes the dependancy query `SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM {{category}}` to get the latest `MAX(update_time)` whose result is stored along with the data. Thats why the query is executed twice.

So the point is that every time you `set()` a value to cache, the dependancy value must be stored along with it since it is needed for the subsequent `get()` queries for checking whether the dependency is changed.

PS:
If you want more clarification check the source code of the `set()` function of your `cache` application component ,it calls the [`evaluateDependency()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCacheDependency#evaluateDependency-detail) function of the [`CDbCacheDependancy`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCacheDependency) class which inturn  calls the [`generateDependentData()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCacheDependency#generateDependentData-detail) which causes the execution of the dependancy query

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. However it's a little bit strange that an opportunity to execute conditional query once is not foreseen like it's done when I use `Yii::app()->db->cache($duration, $dependency)->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();`. A new value of `update_time` for `CDbCacheDependency` could be probably updated somehow on attempt to get cached value. Anyway, you're right - the only way is to look at the sources to find such an opportunity.